# Using Ajax (jQuery load method) to load content page without header and footer

Tags: jquery, ajax

i'm trying to use history API and Ajax for load page content when i click a link. This is the script:

```
$('.menu-item a, .header__logo a').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target != e.currentTarget) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).attr('href');
        loadContent(data);
        history.pushState(null, null, data);
    }
    e.stopPropagation();
});
$(window).on('popstate', function() {
    loadContent(location.pathname);
});
function loadContent(url) {
    $('#wrapper').load(url);
}
```

It's work, but obviously my pages contain header and footer (using get_header() at the beginning and get_footer() at the end): [page home with double header and footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf43P.jpg)

But i would like to have only a permanent header and footer, with the contain of the page that change. It's possible?

This is my header (final part):

```
...
<div class='header__menu'>
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'menu-header')); ?> // menu with relative link to the pages
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
```

and this is an example of my page my page (page-home,...):

```
<?php
/**
 *Template Name: Template Name
 */
get_header();
?>
    <div class="container">...</div>
  </div> // closing wrapper
</main>
<?php get_footer();
```

Comment: can you share your HTML portion? in which you have #wrapper id and also mention your replace portion too

Comment: Sure, now i edit my question

Comment: Done, i added the principal html code

Comment: So, is it really - putting into `$('#wrapper')` content of `$('#wrapper')` from the page you want to load?

Comment: and are you updating container portion? if yes then function loadContent(url) {
    $('#container').load(url);
}

Comment: When i click a link, for example localhost/website/post i load the content to $('#wrapper'). Yes, it works, the container portion change

Comment: No, i'm not updating container, but the div outside. But onestly the container it's the only part of the page i would like to load

Comment: You like to reload div not page right ?

Comment: Yes and i think i found a solution, it possible to load only a specific part of the page simply adding an optional term to load, for example in my case: $('#wrapper').load(url + ' .container');

Answer (score 0):

I can load a specific piece of page simply adding an optional term to load, for example in my case:

```
$('#wrapper').load(url + ' .container');
```

So i don't have double header/footer